# How to abort THTTPReqResp.Execute (from another thread)

Tags: multithreading, http, delphi

I have a worker-thread which is sending XML-requests to a web-application.
In case I need to stop this worker-thread, how to abort the HTTP-execution?

I know that there are timeouts for connect/send/receive, but I'm not aware of any procedure to abort an ongoing HTTP-request...

Here's just a plain example of the HTTP-execution:

```
var
  HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
  Request, Response: TStringStream;
begin
  HTTPReqResp := nil;
  Request  := nil;
  Response := nil;
  try
  HTTPReqResp := THTTPReqResp.Create(nil);

  HTTPReqResp.URL := 'some_url';
  HTTPReqResp.WebNodeOptions := [wnoSOAP12];
  HTTPReqResp.SendTimeout := 60000;
  HTTPReqResp.ConnectTimeout := 60000;
  HTTPReqResp.ReceiveTimeout := 60000;

  Request := TStringStream.Create('<Request_XML>test</Request_XML>', TEncoding.UTF8);
  Response := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8); 

  HTTPReqResp.Execute(Request, Response);
  finally
    Response.Free;
    Request.Free;
    HTTPReqResp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I'm wondering about this quite a while... Hopefully, someone can give me a hint...
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a question: why the multithreading tag? (it seems everything is executed in one thread)

Comment: Hi mjn ^-^   Well, the code is being executed within a worker-thread and THTTPReqResp.Execute is a blocking method. So, in order to abort Execute, it would be called from another thread... So the only ways I currently see are either waiting for a timeout, killing the thread (which I think is not the proper way) or looking for a component which allows to abort...